# Rotating an Object in Unity via SteamVR Controller Rotation, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality, htc-vive

Hello there wise people!

currently, I'm designing a VR Motorcycle Game. Right now, the Steering is controlled by moving your Finger left or right across the Touchpad of the SteamVR Controller.

```
steeringInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
```

What I need is some Input for rotating the Controller left and right, so when I tilt the controller to the right, the steering is also turning right.

I've searched the web for hours but found nothing, that helped me out yet.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What did you not find? How to get rotation of the controller? Or how to rotate your steering wheel?

Comment: Sry if i was unclear. The steering wheel rotates already. I just need to get the rotation of the controller, so that the wheel rotates with the rotation of the controller

Comment: Okay, so you should get the controller's rotation :) `NameOfController.transform.rotation`

Comment: Thank you, but thats not exactly what I'm looking for. Tried this before.
I need to just have the X-Rotation of the controller, so when i turn the controller to the right for 30°, the steering wheel also moves 30°

Comment: `NameOfController.transform.rotation.x` Please refer to the documentation provided by Unity :)

Comment: Hristo is rigth I think. transform.rotation gives you a Vector3. Just get the x member like he said (transform.rotation.x) and that should be it.

Comment: Oh I see! It worked out. Thank you so much!